# Django app is showing an error: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django, heroku-cli, waitress

While I use the url http://0.0.0.0:8000 in browser, it says "The site cannot be reached." How to solve this problem? My Django project name is: `testtodo` and I use this command:

`waitress-serve --port=8000 testtodo.wsgi:application`

When I click on this link on my browser http://0.0.0.0:8000 then it's showing me error, this site can't be reached, and also this error:

```
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Comment: The address `0.0.0.0:8000` is for the app to bind on all available network devices. However in your browser you should go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 (your localhost device).

Comment: ye i know but actually i was deploying my project, And i used waitress server,   i don't want to run my project on locathost , i want to upload on heroku

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error when i was deploying my project refer to this link which can help you -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3AKAdHUY1M .Just keep in mind that you have to ignore this error even i ignored it  and do as he says and by the end of it your project will be deployed.